# Control external camera using iPhone with an app

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, camera, wifi

I am searching for a wifi or bluetooth camera that can be controlled with an iPhone using an app that I will create. I mean I want a programmable camera for iPhone, is this camera exist ?

If you have any info or a product please provide a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could buy a Raspberry Pi with a camera module and build one yourself :)! You could then connect it via Wifi. There are plenty of resources out there, so just Google it.

Comment: But I can't use Raspberry Pi without linked it to pc ? I mean it doesn't have an external battery to work alone.

Comment: Yes you can, a Raspberry Pi is a mini-computer. You only need to connect it to the wifi via either the Wifi Dongle or an Ethernet cable

Comment: and how long it can stay with the camera on?

Comment: As long as you keep the power on :). Just search on Google. If you found this answer helpful, please mark it as correct :).